# Toolbar back click is not working in Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

I have Created Toolbar with back arrow, click is not working

```
 toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar2);
 toolbar.NavigationClick += Back;
 private void Back(object sender, Toolbar.NavigationClickEventArgs e)
 {
    Finish();
 }
```

Comment: you don't do it like that uploading answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OnCreate method do this :

```
ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then override the OnOptionsItemSelected method like this.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
 {
   switch (item.ItemId)
    {
         case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
         Finish();
         return true;

       default:
       return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

If you are using `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7` the `Android.Resource.Id.Home` should be `Resource.Id.Home`.

Also, you only need `ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to show the Home button, no need for the ButtonEnabled call.

Something like this in OnCreate :

```
Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarID);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And something like this in OnOptionsItemSelected:

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
  {
switch (item.ItemId)
  {
  case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
  Finish();
  return true;

      default:
  return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  }
```