# Xamarin.Android: Toolbar is not displayed as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I navigate from my Login Activity to Settings Activity and this is the expected behavior:

[image]

**But when I run my emulator, I see this:**

[image]

The top of my screen is not blue, why?

Here is my **Activity.axml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/settings_toolbar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium">

        <!-- Web Service Urls -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/webServiceUrl"
                android:hint="@string/webServiceUrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                app:MvxBind="Text WebServiceUrl"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my **layout_toolbar.axml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_toolbar_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And this is my **App Themes**:

```
<!-- Base theme applied regardless of API level -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Default App theme applied if no resource style overrides for specific API level -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
```

I also need to draw the arrow button in the toolbar after I move on to another activity, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621225/7462031

Answer (score 1):

you can customize you toolbar and add arrow image in toolbar

like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDashboard"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingEnd="45dp"
            android:paddingRight="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlSymmetry" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNotification"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivHelp"
            android:src="@drawable/notifications_bell_button"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivHelp"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```